# Not able to import packages after build and install using setup.py

Tags: python, setup.py, pypi

I've seen many posts related to `setup.py` installation and build. although I'm not able to figure out a solution for my case.

Directory structure of my code base is:

```
release
├── lib
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── calculator.py
├── release
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── add
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── few_addition.py
│   ├── calculator.egg-info
│   │   ├── PKG-INFO
│   │   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   │   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   │   └── top_level.txt
│   └── sub
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── few_subtraction.py
└── setup.py
```

lib.calculator.py contains below code:

```
def addition(a,b):
    return a+b

def subtraction(a,b):
    return a - b
```

release.add.few_addition.py contains:

```
from lib.calculator import addition

def check_3_4():
    print (addition(3,4))
```

release.sub.few_subtraction.py contains:

```
from lib.calculator import subtraction

def check_3_4():
    print (subtraction(3,4))
```

I tried to package release folder using setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="calculator",
    version='0.1',
    package_dir={'': 'release'},
    packages=['add','sub'],
)
```

But when I'm trying to import this package after installation (using `pip3 install --editable .` ), getting the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'calculator'
```

Import code line is:

```
from release.add import check_3_4
```

Although I see successfully installed calculator package.

Am I doing anything wrong in setup.py?

Purpose is to release two modules `add and subtract`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `package_dir` line. You need to change the `packages` line to `packages=setuptools.find_packages()`, or list all the packages and sub-packages: `packages=['lib', 'release', 'release.add', 'release.sub']`:

```py
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name='calculator',
    version='0.1',
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    # or packages=['lib', 'release', 'release.add', 'release.sub'],
)
```

Comment: Thanks Sinoroc for your input. Still it is throwing the same error.

Comment: You can not import `calculator` directly. Either `from lib import calculator` or `import lib.calculator`.

Comment: Yeah, but issue is same after incorporated the new suggestion:

Comment: ''' 
```>>> import setuptools
>>> print(setuptools.find_packages())
['release', 'lib', 'release.sub', 'release.add']
>>> from release import add
>>> add.check_3_4()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'release.add' has no attribute 'check_3_4'
'''

Comment: You probably need `from release.add.few_addition import check_3_4`.